# Compactness and Normed Linear spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

If the set $S=\{ x \in X : ||x||=1 \}$ in the normed linear space $X$ is compact, how can it be shown that $X$ is finite dimensional?

Comment: Do you know [Riesz's lemma?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz's_lemma)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on Martin's comment, if you know Riesz's lemma, you can use it, supposing that $X$ is infinite-dimensional, to inductively create a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of unit vectors with the property that $x_n$ has distance at least $\tfrac{1}{2}$ to $\mathrm{span} \{x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}\}$ and thus show that no subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy. See this [blog post](http://mathprelims.wordpress.com/2008/07/18/compact-closed-unit-ball-implies-finite-dimension/) for the full argument.

Comment: The blog post assumes that the unit *ball* is compact, not the unit *sphere*, but the argument is exactly the same.

Comment: Good point, thanks.